# Goroutine behaves differently on Windows and Linux

Tags: go, goroutine

I`m new to the GO. I have a following legacy code.

```
var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    go feedChan()

    connString := os.Getenv("DB_CONN")
    var err error

    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", connString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to database at %q: %q\n", connString, err)
    }

    // confirm connection
    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to ping database at %q: %q\n", connString, err)
    }
}


func feedChan() {
    selectQuery, err := db.Prepare(`
        SELECT id, proxy
        FROM proxy
        WHERE fail_count < 2
        ORDER BY date_added DESC, last_used ASC, fail_count ASC
        LIMIT 5
    `)
    ....
```

Following code works on linux. But it fails on windows with nil error on

```
selectQuery, err := db.Prepare(`
```

Which make sense for me, since db initialized after a launch of feedChan goroutine. What doesnt make sense for me is why it work on linux.

So the question is why this code work at linux without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Import `"time"`, put this line after `go feedChan()`, and see if it still works on Linux:

```golang
time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
```

In order to avoid this situation, you could either initialize `db` *before* you spawn the routine (which uses `db`) or use some sort of [barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)):

```golang
func init() {
    barrier := make(chan int)
    go feedChan(barrier)

    connString := os.Getenv("DB_CONN")
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", connString)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to database at %q: %q\n", connString, err)
        // Retry.
    } else {
        barrier <- 1 // Opens barrier.
    }
    // ...
}


func feedChan(barrier chan int) {
    <-barrier // Blocks until db is ready.
    selectQuery, err := db.Prepare(`
        SELECT id, proxy
        FROM proxy
        WHERE fail_count < 2
        ORDER BY date_added DESC, last_used ASC, fail_count ASC
        LIMIT 5
    `)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, obv if initialize after it will work. Thats not my question. I run it a lot on linux and never get this error. But as soon as i launch on windows - nil error ( which is gone if move db init after goroutine). So i want to understand why it never produce this error on linux, but 100% on windows.

Comment: Have you tried to put a sleep after `go feedChan()`? Maybe a few seconds just to make sure the routine starts before `db` is ready. It would be interesting to see if it still works on Linux.

Comment: @Aldarund, like with any case of UB, those kind of question are meaningless. It's UB, so anything could happen. It could break on Linux some day, it could work on it every time or your PC could become alive and run away from you. That doesn't matter. Your code still has a UB. It has two threads of execution that try to access the resource without any kind of synchronization - `func init()` and `func feedChan()`. At this point anything could happen, because it's a race condition between two threads.

Comment: @creker Could you please explain what UB stands for?

Comment: @beatngu13, undefined behavior

Comment: @beatngu13 adding sleep produce same error on linux. So i guess its could be a difference in speed linus vps vs my pretty fast pc on win.

Comment: @Aldarund, it could be because Go runtime is singlethreaded on your linux. Check the value of `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(-1)` on both machines. It will tell you, roughly, how many OS threads Go runtime will use to execute goroutines.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the first lines of your functions I just can say you that your legacy code has a **huge** bug and it can be easily fixed just moving this line `go feedChan()` to the end of the `init()` function.

Also note the main reason is not a race condition, just a matter of wait for the correct initialization of **db** variable.

Comment: Two threads are accessing a shared resource (`dB`) without synchronization. The output of the program fully depends on timing. I'm pretty sure it _is_ a race condition...

Comment: Well yes there's a race condition, but the problem here is an uninitialized variable. All we have to do is start the goroutine `go feedChan()` after the initialization of **db**

Comment: The variable is initialized on one machine, but isn't on the other. How do you explain that? If the thread executing `init()` is fast enough, `db` will be ready _before_ the thread that runs `feedChan()` is accessing it. If not, you'll get that nil error.

Comment: @YandryPozo, the only problem here is a race condition, which triggers an error with uninitialized variable. The latter is an effect, not the cause. Your solution fixes the race condition.